# Uninitialized constant error when trying to refer to a database record within a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, rake

I'm trying to create a rake task that uses a service.  Within that service, I want to load the last saved record of a `MonthlyMetrics` table within my database.

Within my rake file:

```
require 'metrics_service'
namespace :metrics do
  @metrics_service = MetricsService.new

  task :calculate_metrics => [:check_for_new_month, :update_customers, :update_churn, :do_more_stuff] do
    puts "Donezo!"
  end

  # ...more cool tasks

end
```

And my `MetricsService` within `lib/metrics_service.rb`:

```
class MetricsService

  def initialize
    @metrics = MonthlyMetric.last
    @total_customer_count = total_customers.count
    assign_product_values
  end

  # Methods to do all my cool things...

end
```

Whenever I try to run something like `rake:db:migrate`, I get the following error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant MetricsService::MonthlyMetric`

I'm not sure why it's trying to refer to `MonthlyMetric` the way it is... As a class within the `MetricsService` namespace..? It's not like I'm trying to define `MonthlyMetric` as a nested class *within* `MetricsService`... I'm just trying to refer to it as an ActiveRecord query.

I've done other ActiveRecord queries, for example `User`, in other services within the same directory.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you just add  `=> :environment` to the end of your rake task, that may fix the problem.

As in:

`task :calculate_metrics => [:check_for_new_month, :update_customers, :update_churn, :do_more_stuff] => :environment do`

I've run into similar problems where Rails does not initialize the correct environment without this tacked on to each rake task.

Comment: You were completely right!  Although the environment should go within the array of tasks, otherwise it throws an error on the hash rocket.